# How to compute gain margin for this simple example?

Tags: control-theory

I have the simple transfer function:
$$\ L(s) = \frac{3}{s+1}$$

I am stuck computing the gain margin analytically. In Matlab, it tells me that the gain margin is infinite. This is how I am computing by hand:

1. Get $w_{pc}$ by computing L(jw) and making $arg(L(jw_{pc})) = -\pi$
2. Plug this in to $\frac1{|L(jw_{pc})|}$

Doing this, I get $g_m=\frac13$

Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm, when ever does the phase hit $-180^\circ$????? Just plot the function and see what a lower bound on the phase is. I really abhor the complete replacement of pen & graphing by calculators & software.

Comment: What is your $\omega_{pc}$ and how do you get it. You have $0-atan(\omega_{pc}) = -\pi $, and from here we have $\omega_{pc} = tan(\pi) = \inf$

Comment: @PashaPashazade actually, $tan(\pi)=0$...

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right, but still the value you get, i.e. 0, is not solution and you can check it by plugging it into your $L(s)$, and have 3/1 whose angle is zero.

Answer (score 2):

You have

$$
L(j \omega) = \frac{3}{j \omega + 1} = a + j b
$$

with

$$
\begin{align}
a &= \frac{3}{\omega^2 + 1} \\
b &= -\frac{3 \omega}{\omega^2 + 1} 
\end{align}
$$

As you can see, the real part of this complex number is always positive. If this is the [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)#Computing_from_the_real_and_imaginary_part), you can compute the argument of the complex number by

$$
\arg(a + j b) = \arctan(b/a) = -\arctan(\omega)
$$

So, you end up with the equation

$$
\arctan(\omega) = \pi
$$

However, this equation has no real solution because $\arctan : \mathbb{R} \mapsto (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$ never reaches $\pi$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! I'm confused because -- can't you take the tangent in both sides of the equation to get w = 0?

Comment: @Bee This Wikipedia article might be interesting for you: [Inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions). In general, you have to restrict the domain of $\tan$ so that an inverse function exists.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity from phase wrapping I prefer using the complex values directly based on the Nyquist plot (in which you want to avoid the minus one point) instead of the Bode plot. From this it follows that the imaginary part of $L(j\,\omega_{pc})$ should be zero (and the real part negative if you want a positive gain margin) instead of $\arg(L(j\,\omega_{pc}) = -\pi$.

Comment: So, whenever we can't find a solution to the equation, that means that the phase plot never crosses -180º, and thus the gain margin is infinite?

Comment: Just plot the function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8y7n3b0sjg

Comment: By convention, GM is taken to be $\infty$ if the phase never crosses $-180^\circ$.

Comment: @copper.hat got it. I have been plotting the functions in Matlab, but I have a final exam tomorrow and I need to be able to solve analytically too!!

Comment: I understand, but a quick plot by hand will show that no solution exists.

Comment: Just to clarify: whenever I am left with the equation $arctan(F(\omega)) = \pi$, whatever the expression $F(\omega)$ may be, no solution exists and thus the gain margin is infinite? Also, are there any more of these equations I should watch out for?